# Validate horizontal tab forms on click of next button Jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to do some validations on my horizontal tab form using jquery on click of **Next** button. 
Below is my HTML code for the tabs:

```
<div class="form-wrap">
<form action="functions.php" method="POST" id="quoteForm">
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container slider-form pb-5">
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="row tab-title">
        <div class="col-md-4 py-3">Select A Service</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 py-3">Choose Your Branch</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 py-3">Personal Informations</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" id="service-type">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <label>Car make<span>*</span></label>
                    <div class="select-custom">
                        <select class="form-control" name="carbrand" id="carbrand">
                            <option value="All">All</option>
                            <?php
                        $get=$config->getAllCarBrands();
                        while($row=$get->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['brand_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['brand_name']; ?></option>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        </select>
                        <span class="req" id="brand_error" style="display: none">Required</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <label>Car range<span>*</span></label>
                    <div class="select-custom">
                        <select class="form-control" name="carrange" id="carrange">
                            <option value="All">All</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="req" id="sub_brand_error" style="display: none">Required</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 pt-4 border-right-1">
                    <div class="form-group border p-2">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" name="carservices[]" value="Tyre Replacement">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Tyre Replacement</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group border p-2">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck2" name="carservices[]" value="Fitting and Balancing">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Fitting and Balancing</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 pt-4 pt-sm-0">
                    <div class="form-group border p-2">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck6" name="carservices[]" value="Battery">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck6">Battery</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group border p-2">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck7" name="carservices[]" value="Air Conditioning">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck7">Air Conditioning</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="req" id="service_error" style="display: none">Required</span>
            </div>
            <div class="text-right btn-resize">
                <!-- Add Arrows -->
                <div class="form-btn-next w-auto" id="btn-selectservice">next <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <label>Select a centre</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="radio radio-scroller row">
                        <div class="radio-custom col-md-6 mb-3">
                            <input type="radio" name="selectedbranch" id="radio5" class="css-checkbox" value="Al Mushrif"/>
                            <label for="radio5" class="css-label radGroup1">
                                <div class="dealer-name mb-2">ABC</div>
                                <div class="dealer-address mb-1">Location, City</div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio-custom col-md-6 mb-3">
                            <input type="radio" name="selectedbranch" id="radio6" class="css-checkbox" value="Al Falah"/>
                            <label for="radio6" class="css-label radGroup1">
                                <div class="dealer-name mb-2">DEF</div>
                                <div class="dealer-address mb-1">location, City</div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-right btn-resize">
                            <!-- Add Arrows -->
                            <div class="form-btn-next w-auto">next <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></div>
                        </div>
            <div class="text-left btn-resize mt-4">
                <!-- Add Arrows -->
                <div class="form-btn-prev w-auto d-inline-block"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i> Return to list</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide" id="info-tab">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>Full name<span>*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" id="fullname">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-12 mt-3">
                    <label>I wish to be contacted by</label>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <div class="radio-custom">
                            <input type="radio" name="contactby" id="radio7" class="css-checkbox" value="Telephone or Email">
                            <label for="radio7" class="css-label radGroup1">Telephone or Email</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio-custom">
                            <input type="radio" name="contactby" id="radio8" class="css-checkbox" checked="checked" value="Email only">
                            <label for="radio8" class="css-label radGroup1">Email only</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio-custom">
                            <input type="radio" name="contactby" id="radio9" class="css-checkbox" value="Telephone only">
                            <label for="radio9" class="css-label radGroup1">Telephone only</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>Email<span>*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emailid" id="emailid">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>Telephone number<span>*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneno" id="phoneno">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-right btn-resize">
                <!-- Add Arrows -->
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="quote">
                <input type="submit" class="form-btn-submit w-auto" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
            <div class="text-left btn-resize mt-4">
                <!-- Add Arrows -->
                <div class="form-btn-prev w-auto d-inline-block"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i> Return to list</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                  
</div>
</form>
```

custom.js

```
$('#btn-selectservice').click(function(event){

var carbrand = $('#carbrand').val();
var subbrand = $('#carrange').val();
var service1 = $('#customCheck1').val();
var service2 = $('#customCheck2').val();
var service3 = $('#customCheck3').val();
var service4 = $('#customCheck6').val();
var service5 = $('#customCheck7').val();

if(carbrand === "" && subbrand === "")
{
    alert("Car brand empty");
    $("#brand_error").show();
    $("#sub_brand_error").show();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("#btn-selectservice").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#btn-selectservice").attr("disabled", true);
}
})
```

I above validation If I click the next button without selecting any car brands the alert is showing but its navigating to next tab. I tried using `event.stopImmediatePropagation` on button click, but that's also not working. How can I validate the **Next** buttons for all my tabs? Can anyone please help me out! Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**

I have updated my custom.js as below

```
$('#btn-selectservice').click(function(event){
alert("button clicked");
var carbrand = $('#carbrand').val();
var subbrand = $('#carrange').val();
var checkbox = $('input:checkbox').is(':checked');

if((carbrand == "" || carbrand == "All") && (subbrand == "" ||  subbrand == "All") && (checkbox == "false"))
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("#brand_error").show();
        $("#sub_brand_error").show();
        $("#service_error").show();
    }
else if(carbrand == "" || carbrand == "All")
    {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $("#brand_error").show();
    }
else if(subbrand == "" ||  subbrand == "All")
    {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $("#sub_brand_error").show();
    }
else if(checkbox == "false")
    {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $("#service_error").show();
    }
else
    {
        $( "#btn-selectservice" ).trigger( "click" );
    }
})
```

Now what happens is the error field is showing and the **next** navigation is disabled when any field is empty, Unfortunately If all the validations are correct and when I click the next button it goes to infinite loop. How can I make it work if the validations are satisfied.

Comment: if the carbrand and subbrand is null you can use return false; after alert("car brand empty")

Comment: Adding `return false` doesn't make any changes in the result.